# Schematron Termination

Tags: schematron

I would like to exit the validation if a phase fails (the idea is phase 1 invocation mismatch checking, phase 2 content checking.

I can structure my testing in phases but how do I get Schematron to exit gracefully rather than going to the next phase?

Peter

Comment: What is your environment? Can you use XProc or do you use an editor?